# Storage way of log files

Tags: database, logging, machine-learning, filesystems

I have a system which is receiving log files from different places through http(>100k producers per day), I would like to use these log files as part of input data of RecSys.
My question is: Consider the uses of the log files,which is better way to store them? Text file or database?
Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

since you said a lot data come.. I prefer text file.. 
first you should have format for the log like

- filename format => example: server_{year}_{month}
- input format => example: {time} {ip} {status} {text}

database is nice.. but try not put the log in same database with your main database.. 
remember.. **play safe**

Comment: Thanks for reply. Since recommendation system will use these log files as input data,there would be some manipulation of data.Maybe database query do it conveniently.Consider this, is it better to store them in database?

Comment: this manipulation must be recorded right? I think You must put in different table as history that include who have manipulate the data. remember to make sure the table unable to edit,  only read and write.